# Assembly procedure printing message three times

Tags: assembly, procedure, tasm

## Code

```
.model small
.data    
prompt_msg db "Please enter your length:$"

.stack 100h 

.code       
main proc
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax
mov es,ax
call prompt_user

;exit
mov ah,01h
int 21h
mov ah,4ch

int 21h
endp main

prompt_user proc
call NewLine
call CarriageReturn
mov ah,09h
lea dx,prompt_msg
int 21h
ret

endp prompt_user

NewLine proc
mov ah,09h
mov dx,0dh
int 21h
ret

endp NewLine

CarriageReturn proc
mov ah,09h
mov dx,0ah
int 21h
ret

endp CarriageReturn 

end main
```

### Desciption of code

This code prints the message without new line and prints thrice overlapping the previous message. I use Tasm and this is 8086 assembly.

It prints something like this

"your length here: enter your length here: Please enter your length here:"

Comment: It seems like you forgot to ask a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within your two procedures `newline` and `carriagereturn`, you are setting **dx** to the values 13 and 10 respectively, then executing function **09** which is `display string beginning at **DS:DX**.

Now, `prompt_msg` is located at **DS:0000** so it obediently prints the message from the 14th charater, then again from the 11th, and then the entire message when **dx** is loaded with the offset of `prompt_msg` = **0000**

I suspect right strongly that you should call function **02** not **09**, which outputs the character in **DL** (hence, it's probably only necessary to load **DL**, not **DX** in those procedures.)

Comment: I know found out my mistake right after i posted it, thanks for explaining.